# Delete Message When Detects A Certain Word

Tags: c#, .net, discord, discord.net

I am pretty new to making discord bots and have tried to make a filter to when my bot detects a certain word in a message it will delete it. It is throwing no errors, it just will not delete the message. I might just have the code in the wrong spot, but I do not know. If anyone can help me out, I'd appreciate it.

```
        private async Task BadWordsWarn(SocketMessage message)
        {
            string[] badWords = File.ReadAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/wordstodelete.txt");

            
                if (badWords.Any(message.Content.Contains))
                    await message.DeleteAsync();
            
        }
```

Comment: have you checked the content of `badWords` after is is read, to make sure it matches what you expect?

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. Yes I did but it did not delete anything which surprised me.

Comment: In the message you expect to be filtered, does the "bad word" have the same case as defined in `wordstodelete.txt`?  [`string.Contains(string)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.contains#System_String_Contains_System_String_) performs case-sensitive `char` comparisons.  On .NET (Core) 2.1 and above you can call an overload that takes a `StringComparison` parameter; otherwise, call [`string.IndexOf(string, StringComparison)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_System_StringComparison_) and test against `!= -1`.

Answer (score 1):

How are you calling `BadWordsWarn`? I suspect that you perhaps are not awaiting the async call, or `badWords` isn't actually being populated for the version of code you're running e.g. is the file being copied to the output directory if you're running the release version?

The C# code works - not optimal as the `badWords` array should be passed in as opposed to being read every time but there's nothing wrong with the syntax.

Perhaps the Discord message contents is in JSON and needs to be parsed?

If it's a string, this code is case-insensitive & definitely works.

```cs
var badWords = new [] {
  "grape",
  "apple"
};
var messageContent = "good good good grape";

foreach(var word in badWords) {
  var contentHasBadWord = messageContent.IndexOf(word, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;

  if (contentHasBadWord) {
    Console.WriteLine("Bad word found - " + word);
    // delete message
    break;
  }
}
```

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DBxzjJ)

Comment: It was async but I did figure it out the problem. The code was working but one of my admins removed the delete message permissions from our bot role without me knowing. All I need to figure out is how to make the code case insensitive.

Comment: @JejejejDnjdjdnd Updated for a case-insensitive version, let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you for this code. It require quite a bit of modifications but it sure as hell helped me out and worked out in the end. Thank you very much!